# SQL Average only weekdays

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a data table in MS Access as such:

```
[DateID]   |[NameID]|[ValueID]
01/01/2019 |Ben     |5
01/01/2019 |Ace     |6
01/01/2019 |Ken     |7
01/01/2019 |Jon     |10
.
.
.
03/01/2019 |Ben     |8
03/01/2019 |Ken     |55
03/01/2019 |Jan     |52
```

Basically multiple `ValueID` entries in a single day under different names with at least 100+ entries per day.

I need to draw out the average `ValueID` for weekdays across 2 specific date and the sql code is executed via Excel VB. So far the sql code have cannot differentiate between weekdays and weekends.

Code I have that works so far: `SELECT AVG([ValueID]) FROM [TABLE] WHERE [DATEID] BETWEEN #10 Jan 2018# AND #15 Feb 2018#`

Have scoured the around for a bit. The closest I've gotten is `SELECT AVG([ValueID]) FROM [TABLE] WHERE ([DATEID] BETWEEN #10 Jan 2018# AND #15 Feb 2018#) AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [DATEID]) IN ('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY')`

However, it gives me an `Undefined function 'DATENAME' in expression` error. Not sure if I'm even using this function right if I'm totally honest.

I understand I could technically export the range of dates into the Excel sheet then exclude from there but it could potentially be a 10k+ data points export. Therefore would prefer to do it via sql as it looks cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use literals, as these are localised, thus:

```
SELECT 
    AVG([ValueID]) 
FROM 
    [TABLE] 
WHERE 
    ([DATEID] BETWEEN #2018/01/10# AND #2018/01/15#) 
    AND 
    Weekday([DATEID], 2) < 6
```

In function *Weekday*, the parameter 2 is for *Monday* as the first day of the week and, then, 6 is *Saturday*.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`WeekdayName`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekdayname-function-638adafd-9923-455b-a2fe-46cf50d8d751) and [`Weekday`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekday-function-05d360d7-2c3f-4691-9448-c96ea0351940), so this will do it:

```
...AND UCase(WeekdayName(Weekday([DATEID], 2))) NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
```

Maybe you need to change 2 to 1 (or other) to get the correct day name (2 stands for Monday as start of week).